# php script to load contents of a file into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have written a php script to insert the contents of a text file into mysql database and the content of my file **a.txt** is

**\n is used for a new line**

i want it to be loaded into the database including the special character 
      **\n**

as it is... 
But it is loading only          " **is used for a new line**"
kindly help me out...
thanx

```
<?php
$filename = "a.txt";
$f = fopen($filename, 'r');
$total_contents = fread($f, filesize($filename));
print $total_contents;
mysql_connect("localhost", "datab_user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("datab_name") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name
(id,content) VALUES( 333,'$total_contents' ) ")
or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: can't you use load data infile - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape it. If you want a newline in Mysql, send **\n** to the server, if you want a **\n**, send **\\n**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the \n to appear inside the DB as is (ie. as **\** followed by **n** and not as a newline), then you have to escape it, so you have to send **\\n is used for a new line** to the DB.

BTW You could also use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) if you just want to read the full file contents into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the PHP manual for mysql_real_escape_string to escape input into a mysql databse.